# What is the best way to check if a string contains any numbers?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a check to make sure the user remembers to enter the house number as well as road number in the address.

how would I go about checking to see if a NSString contains 0-9 number characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be as simple as using [`rangeOfCharacterFromSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfCharacterFromSet%3a):

```
NSCharacterSet * set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

if ([aString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"This string contains illegal characters");
}
```

You could also give a look at regular expressions, if you would like to do something fancier with your validation, but in order to just check if a string contains any number, the above is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `-[NSString (NSRange)rangeOfCharacterFromSet:(NSCharacterSet *)aSet]`
and `+[NSCharacterSet (id)decimalDigitCharacterSet]`.